# Entity Framework two DbContext in one database

Tags: entity-framework, migration

Present

1. One MS SQL DataBase 'DB';
2. DbContext1 with migration;
3. DbContext2 migration not needed;

Task

1. How make them live in the same database 'DB'?
2. How use migration DbContext1 but not to delete data DbContext2 (table names do not intersect)?
3. How write method RecreateDbContext2

sample this

```
public void RecreateDbContext2(DbContext2 dbContext2)
{
    dbContext2<Table1>.DropTable();
    dbContext2<Table1>.CreateTable();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at EF6 and multi tenant migrations [here](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Multi-tenant%20Migrations)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I need, but it's an alpha.